# Добавить файл перевода в Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

На сайте использую фразы, которые не входят ни в один компонент. Как мне сделать файл переводов для этих фраз? Уже все посмотрел - не нашел

Answer (score 0):

Для таких фаилов создаешь папку lang в папке шаблона

**/bitrix/templates/< идентификатор шаблона >/lang/**

Почитать про реализацию этого подхода можно тут

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=3396&LESSON_PATH=3913.4564.4926.3396